# Realm swift notification stops firing

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have set an observer for a live result object.

```
let token = realm.objects(RealmObject.self).observe(on: realmQueue) { changeset in
   print(changeset)
}
```

It works as expected for the most part, it triggers when I add/delete or edit RealmObject type objects in/to the realm db.
My issue happens when I try to replace the whole array of objects with a new array. Basically what I do is I get all objects of type RealmObjects delete them and then I add the new array of RealmObjects. Now the issues is if I do the delete and add in one write transaction the notification mechanism seems to break, it doesn't trigger for this operation. On the other hand if I separate the delete and add into different write transactions then everything works with notifications (except I get two notifications as expected in this case, but it's not what I want).
Am I missing something and doing something wrong ?

```
// triggers notifications
let objectsToDelete = realm.objects(RealmObject.self)
try realm.write {
    if !objectsToDelete.isEmpty {
        realm.delete(objectsToDelete)
    }
}
try realm.write {
    realm.add(objects)
}
// doesn't trigger notification
let objectsToDelete = realm.objects(RealmObject.self)
try realm.write {
    if !objectsToDelete.isEmpty {
        realm.delete(objectsToDelete)
    }
    realm.add(objects)
}
```

**edit: After further investigation it seems that this only happens in a specific case. When replacing the items with the same number of items and same primary key (even though some other properties ore different).**

```
class RealmObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var primary: String!
    @objc dynamic var summary: String!
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "primary"
    }
}

extension RealmObject {
    convenience init(summary: Int, uuid: String = UUID().uuidString) {
        self.init()
        self.primary = uuid
        self.summary = "Object nr. \(summary)"
    }
}
let sharedKeys = [UUID().uuidString, UUID().uuidString, UUID().uuidString]
let initialObjects = [RealmObject(summary: 0, uuid: sharedKeys[0]),RealmObject(summary: 1, uuid: sharedKeys[1]),RealmObject(summary: 2, uuid: sharedKeys[2])]
let replaceObjects = [RealmObject(summary: 3, uuid: sharedKeys[0]),RealmObject(summary: 4, uuid: sharedKeys[1]),RealmObject(summary: 5, uuid: sharedKeys[2])]
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and ran both the first section of code and the second section of code and it worked correctly and identically. Both resulted in new objects being written and the observe function continued to fire events on the new objects. To verify, I ran both sections of code and modified the resulting objects using Realm Studio while the app was running the events fired in both cases correctly.

Comment: @Jay don't really know what is going on then, this code I tried in a playground as well in the notification doesn't trigger for the second section and it just fails to work after that no matter what I do. What realm, xcode version did you try with?

Comment: edited my question with some new information

Comment: XCode 11.3.1, Realm API 5.1, and today 5.2. Why/how would you replace objects with the same primary key? Primary keys should always be unique. I am also curious about this `convenience init(summary: Int, uuid: String = UUID().uuidString) {` - why are you doing this `uuid: String = UUID().uuidString` part in the init?

Answer (score 0):

This rings bells (I worked on the Realm C# team 2015-2017).

I'm fairly certain it is because of optimisations around primary keys and their use *within* a transaction, combined with how the notification structure is built. Strictly speaking, it is a bug. You might expect  these would be coming out as Delete+Add or as a Change record in the notification.

You are fighting a deep core assumption about how primary keys are used and optimisations that are intended to keep them working incredibly fast. I doubt strongly it will get fixed.

Switching to non-primary keys but indexed fields would probably get around this but complicate the rest of your code, sorry.

It's also possible you don't need these to be indexed at all, depending on your data volumes. Realm does some incredibly fast searching so I always recommend people try a non-indexed search first to see if that's enough.